# JAX-RS (RestEasy) middleware: brokering client request

Tags: java, jax-rs, resteasy

This question is directly related to the question asked by @Mario at the following link
[Using JAX-RS (RESTEasy) as middleware: brokering a client's request to another server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24742305/using-jax-rs-resteasy-as-middleware-brokering-a-clients-request-to-another-s)

I don't understand why the response from the service cannot be directly relayed back to the client. Consider the following code

Postman (client) makes a GET request on resource **ServiceA** on the URI below:

```
http://localhost:8080/A/ServiceA
```

**ServiceA** looks like below:

```
@Path("ServiceA")
public class ServiceA {

    private static final String BASE_URI = "http://localhost:8080/B/";
    // call ServiceB at localhost:8080/B/ServiceB
    // <ServiceB> path is resolved via Proxy

    @GET
    @Formatted
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
    public Response show() {

        ResteasyClient resteasyClient = new ResteasyClientBuilder().build();
        ResteasyWebTarget webTarget = resteasyClient.target(BASE_URI);
        ServiceBProxy serviceBProxy = webTarget.proxy(ServiceBProxy.class);
        return serviceBProxy.show();
    }
}
```

**ServiceA** calls REST method **show()** using **Proxy** which looks like this:

```
@Path("ServiceB")
public interface ServiceBProxy {
    @GET
    @Formatted
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
    public Response show();
}
```

And finally **ServiceB** looks like this:

```
@Path("ServiceB")
public class ServiceB {

@GET
@Formatted
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
public Response show() {
    return Response.status(200).entity(new  Employee("John", "Doe", 32)).build();
}
```

I'm thinking that the ServiceA just returns the response back to the client, and all is well. But the client is getting nothing back.

Of-course I tried the solution mentioned in post linked above. And it works.

```
@GET
@Formatted
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
public Response show() {

    ResteasyClient resteasyClient = new ResteasyClientBuilder().build();
    ResteasyWebTarget webTarget = resteasyClient.target(BASE_URI);
    ServiceBProxy serviceBProxy = webTarget.proxy(ServiceBProxy.class);
    Response response = serviceBProxy.show()
    Employee employee = response.readEntity(Employee.class);
    response.close();
    return Response.status(200).entity(employee).build();
}
```

I don't understand **Why**? Directly accessing **ServiceB** returns back the result; Relaying it back using **ServiceA** does not? Could someone provide me the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`javax.ws.rs.core.Response` is an abstract class.  The implementation to receive data from B won`t be the same that to send data to A. Althought the interface is the same, they can not be interchanged

`Response` is not an object instance with the data entity embedded. Think of a pipe to transfer data from B to the client through A. A unwraps the message from B using an `InputStream`, gets the entity and wraps it to the client with an `OutputStream`

Comment: Thank you very much for clear explanation. It makes perfect sense. In-fact that also answers related question I had i.e. directly accessing the resource **ServiceB** with a client (Postman) delivers an XML response as expected. Looking at the **Response** reference, it can be seen that entity **Employee** is serialized; where as in **ServiceA** code, the **Response** received seems to be different. This is because of the different implementation of **Response** as you mentioned and therefore empty display at client. Am I correct?

Comment: The response in both cases is `application/xml` so the final content in the same. If you are viewing different serialization into the object, the reason only can be the different class implementations to process the streams